# Python 3.7.2 32-Bit ZIP Password cracker

Tags: python, python-3.x, forgot-password

**(Sorry for bad english, im german)**
I was trying to make a zip password cracker, because i lost the password for my Website Sourcecode. But i get following Error over and over again.

CODE:

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import string
from threading import Thread
import traceback


def crack(zip, pdw):
    try:
        zip.extractall(pdw=str.encode(pdw))
        print('Geschafft: Passwort ist ' + pdw)
    except:
        pass

zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile("D:\-----[WEBSITE]-----\Source1.zip")
myLetters = string.ascii_letters
for i in range(3,10):
    for j im map(''.join, itertools.product(myLetters, repeat=i)):
        t = Thread(target=crack, args=(zipfile, j))
        t.start()
```

> invalid syntax (, line 18) pylint(syntax-error) [18,1]

Comment: Could you add the full error stacktrace, so we can see the specific line that raises the error?

Comment: Paths contain backslashes - you need to escape them or use raw strings if handlign paths: `zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(  r"D:\-----[WEBSITE]-----\Source1.zip")` and the typo - see answer -voting to close as typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mis-spelled `in` as `im`

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import string
from threading import Thread
import traceback


def crack(zip, pdw):
    try:
        zip.extractall(pdw=str.encode(pdw))
        print('Geschafft: Passwort ist ' + pdw)
    except:
        pass

zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile("D:\-----[WEBSITE]-----\Source1.zip")
myLetters = string.ascii_letters
for i in range(3,10):
    for j in map(''.join, itertools.product(myLetters, repeat=i)):
        t = Thread(target=crack, args=(zipfile, j))
        t.start()
```

Comment: Now i got 2 Issues. "Anomalous backslash in string: '\-'. String constant might be missing an r prefix." and "Anomalous backslash in string: '\S'. String constant might be missing an r prefix."

Comment: @LeqitShxdow to resolve this error please use `zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile( r"D:\-----[WEBSITE]-----\Source1.zip")` as Patrick as rightly pointed out in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You put im instead of in :)
The error is at line 18 in the for cicle.